# SQL groupby month

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

This is my query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Expr1, name, appointment_date 
FROM ReportingTable 
GROUP BY name, appointment_date
```

I want to group the appointment_date column by month as follows:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Expr1, name, appointment_date
FROM ReportingTable
GROUP BY name, MONTH(appointment_date)
```

But my query raises the following error:

> Column "appointment_date" is invalid in the selected list because it
>   is not contained in either aggregate function or groupby clause .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work:

```
SELECT        COUNT(*) AS Expr1, name, MONTH(appointment_date) AS appointment_month
FROM            ReportingTable
GROUP BY name, appointment_month
```